# Adding and reading a config.ini file inside python package

Tags: python, python-2.7, import, config, configparser

I am writing my first python package which I want to upload on PyPI. I structured my code based on this [blog post](https://gehrcke.de/2014/02/distributing-a-python-command-line-application/).

I want to store user setting in a config.ini file. Read it once(every time the package is run) in separate python module in same package and save user setting in global variables of that module. Later import those in other modules.

To recreate the error I just edited few lines of code, in the template described in the blog post. (Please refer to it since it would take too much typing to recreate entire thing here in question.)

The only difference is that my `stuff.py` reads from config file like this:

```
from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser

config = SafeConfigParser()
config.read('config.ini')

TEST_KEY = config.get('main', 'test_key')
```

Here are the contents of `config.ini` (placed in same dir as `stuff.py`):

```
[main]
test_key=value
```

And my `bootstrap.py` just imports and print the `TEST_KEY`

```
from .stuff import TEST_KEY

def main():
    print(TEST_KEY)
```

But on executing the package, the import fails give this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "D:\Coding\bootstrap\bootstrap-runner.py", line 8, in <module>
    from bootstrap.bootstrap import main
    File "D:\Coding\bootstrap\bootstrap\bootstrap.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .stuff import TEST_KEY
    File "D:\Coding\bootstrap\bootstrap\stuff.py", line 14, in <module>
    TEST_KEY = config.get('main', 'test_key')
    File "C:\Python27\Lib\ConfigParser.py", line 607, in get
    raise NoSectionError(section)
ConfigParser.NoSectionError: No section: 'main'
```

Import keeps giving **ConfigParser.NoSectionError**, but if you build/run only stuff.py(I use sublime3), the module gives no errors and printing `TEST_KEY` gives `value` as output.

Also, this method of import does work when I just use 3 files(config, stuff, main) in a dir and just execute the main as a script. But there I had to import it like this

```
from stuff import TEST_KEY
```

I'm just using the explicit relative imports as described in that post but don't have enough understanding of those. I guess the error is due to project structure and import, since running `stuff.py` as standalone script raises no `ConfigParser.NoSectionError`.

Other method to read the config file once and then use data in other modules will be really helpful as well.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is your problem, but the ConfigParser.read() function does not raise an Exception if the file can't be found or there is some kind of IO error (see the docs).  If it can't read the file, it will fail silently and just initialize to an empty dictionary,

Comment: @PaulCornelius But if you run the stuff.py alone it does read the ini file and gives not errors. Only when I'm importing TEST_KEY like that, it raises that error.

Comment: That's my point.  I thought it might be useful to isolate the reason why the program is failing, which you can do by inspecting the returned value from ConfigParser.read().  I can't follow what you're saying about standalone versus import versus files, etc.  I don't know what you mean by "when I execute the package."

Answer (score 9):

There are two aspects to this question. **First** is the weird behavior of `ConfigParser`. When `ConfigParser` is unable to locate the `.ini` file; it never gives, for some annoying reason, an `IOError` or an error which indicates that it is unable to read the file.

In my case it keeps giving `ConfigParser.NoSectionError` when the `section` is clearly present. When I caught the `ConfigParser.NoSectionError` error it gave an `ImportError`! But it never tells you that it is simply unable to read the file.

**Second** is how to safely read the **data files that are included in your package**. The only way I found to do this was to use the `__file__` parameter. This is how you would safely read the `config.ini` in the above question, for Python27 and Python3:

```
import os

try:
    # >3.2
    from configparser import ConfigParser
except ImportError:
    # python27
    # Refer to the older SafeConfigParser as ConfigParser
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser as ConfigParser

config = ConfigParser()

# get the path to config.ini
config_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), 'config.ini')

# check if the path is to a valid file
if not os.path.isfile(config_path):
    raise BadConfigError # not a standard python exception

config.read(config_path)

TEST_KEY = config.get('main', 'test_key') # value
```

This relies on the fact that `config.ini` is located inside our package `bootstrap` and is expected to be shipped with it.

The important bit is how you get the `config_path`:

```
config_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), 'config.ini')
```

`__file__` refers to the location of current `script` that is being executed. In my question that means the location of `stuff.py`, that is inside the `bootstrap` folder, and so is `config.ini`.

The above line of code then means; get the absolute path to `stuff.py`; from that get path to the directory containing it; and join that with `config.ini` (since it is in same directory) to give absolute path to the `config.ini`. Then you can proceed to read it and raise an `exception` just in case.

This will work even when you release your package on `pip` and a user installs it from there.

As a **bonus**, and digressing from the question a bit, if you are releasing your package on `pip` with data files inside your package, you must tell `setuptools` to include them inside you package when you build `sdist` and `bdist`s. So to include the `config.ini` in above package add the following lines to `setup` class call in `setup.py`:

```
include_package_data = True,
package_data = {
    # If any package contains *.ini files, include them
    '': ['*.ini'],
},
```

But it still may not work in some cases eg. building wheels etc. So you also do the same in your `MANIFEST.IN` file:

```
include LICENSE
include bootstrap/*.ini
```

Answer (score 3):

abhimanyuPathania : The issue is with path of `config.ini` in `stuff.py`. Change `config.read('config.ini')` to `config.read('./bootstrap/config.ini')` in `stuff.py`. I tried the solution. It works for me.

Enjoying Pythoning...

Comment: yes it does work. But now if I build stuff.py standalone, it gives the same error. So issue is definitely with the path. Can you please edit your answer and explain a bit more?

Comment: Sure... What steps are you doing to build in stand alone and how are you executing them... Please elaborate

Comment: By build I mean just open stuff.py in sublime and (Ctrl + B) to run it. Or you can open cmd prompt, cd to inner bootstrap dir and then: python stuff.py

Comment: @abhimanyuPathania  The path is relative ..it depends on who is calling ....
if you are executing  `python stuff.py` then it is `config.ini` 
if you are executing  `python -m bootstrap` then it is `./bootstrap/config.ini`

Comment: ok. Thanks. I will dig a bit more into relative and absolute paths and will mark your answer as accepted later.