# Store user settings in Python script

Tags: python, application-settings

I created a Python package that is actually a command line interface. Everything works fine, but I would like to be able to store simple user settings (a few values) in some file (json, yaml, or whatever). Handling such files itself is not a problem, but I don't know where I could store them. My program can be installed using `pip install https://github.com/repo` and works fully off-line.

It seems that Python does not allow me to store settings files in the same folder, where the compiled program itself is located (Programs\Python\Python38\Scripts) which makes sense, but I don't know how to do it any other way.

Comment: Have you considered using an environment variables to set the path of a settings file. And use the environment variable in the script.

Comment: Or another option to pass the path of a settings file as a command line parameter. Something like `cli-tool -f /path/to/settings.json`

Comment: You could store that file in one of the "standard" directories used on OS's, this will require you to check if the user is on Mac/Windows/etc though. For example, on Windows this path is usually %AppData%.

Comment: @ShoaibAhmed Well, I can use environmental variables to set the path, but where can I store the file itself? Asking the user to take care of the location themselves is not a very good idea. If I have misunderstood something then I'm sorry, this is the first time I am doing this kind of thing (storing settings files).

Comment: @dir Is there a tool that will do this for me? unfortunately I only use Windows and have no idea what the appropriate places are on other systems.

Comment: I think using the standard library configparser and taking a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35563606/9267296) might solve it. I'm not 100% sure if you can store changes though...

Comment: @MichałDobranowski I understand now based on the other comments. I don't think there is one perfect solution, it would depend on how this settings file will be created and how it would be used. taking inspiration from @dir and AWS CLI, you can create a command `cli-tool configure` that goes through a setup process and creates a file at the `%HOME%` directory. If the file is missing you can ask the user to run `configure`. You can also allow a user to pass another settings file path as a parameter in the CLI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspired by the comments under the question, I searched a little bit more and found the answer to my problem.

I store my settings file in `C:\users\me\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\my_package\config.json` which can be accessed with

```py
os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), 'config.json')
```

I haven't tested this on Linux or macOS yet, but I think it will work.

**EDIT**: Unfortunately it does not work on Linux without sudo. For this reason, I used the following:

```py
os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~"), '.my_package_name', 'config.json')
```

Comment: You might want to check the lifecycle of the package folder. A user may lose their settings if they uninstall and reinstall the package. But it would work well when a user would install multiple instances in virtual environments.