# How to include a .ini file in my python package when installing via pip from TFS2017?

Tags: python, manifest, setuptools

I have a library that requires a .ini file at some point (a default config file if none provided by the user).

Here is the hierarchy, with the required file marked:

```bash
├───src
│   ├───main
│   │   │   MANIFEST.in
│   │   │   setup.py
│   │   │
│   │   ├───matmuttools
│   │   │   │   matmut_logging.py
│   │   │   │   proxy.py
│   │   │   │   PROXY_USAGE.md
│   │   │   │   singleton.py
│   │   │   │   __init__.py
│   │   │   │
│   │   │   │
│   │   │   ├───ql
│   │   │   │   │   default_config.ini    <----
│   │   │   │   │   query_language.py
│   │   │   │   │   tsql.py
│   │   │   │   │   __init__.py
```

I have tried several things, based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35236223/adding-and-reading-a-config-ini-file-inside-python-package) and this [doc](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/using-manifest-in/)

Using the following in the manifest does not "package" the ini file:

```
include matmuttools/ql/default_config.ini
```

Using setup.py, the following does not work either:

```
include_package_data=True,
package_data={'matmuttools': ['*.ini']}
```

I know that the file is not included because this file is read by `configparser` and it throws me an error when looking for a section contained in the file.

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matmuttools/ql/query_language.py", line 41, in __init__
    raise ValueError(f"{self.language_name} not found in config file")
ValueError: TSQL not found in config file
```

Moreover, using ls to check out the package when installed does not show the file:

```
ls -lR /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matmuttools/*

/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matmuttools/ql:
total 16
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  120 Sep 30 08:44 __init__.py
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Sep 30 08:44 __pycache__
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2159 Sep 30 08:44 query_language.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  478 Sep 30 08:44 tsql.py
```

The library is installed via:

pip install "git+http:myurl"

---

**How can I ship correctly this configuration file with my library ?**

---

Content of the wheel:

Building the wheel with:

```
python setup.py bdist_wheel
```

It contains:

```
$ zipinfo dist/matmuttools-3.2.0-py3-none-any.whl 
Archive:  dist/matmuttools-3.2.0-py3-none-any.whl
Zip file size: 12646 bytes, number of entries: 14
-rw-rw-rw-  2.0 fat      153 b- defN 22-Sep-29 10:12 matmuttools/__init__.py
-rw-rw-rw-  2.0 fat     9841 b- defN 22-Jun-13 06:37 matmuttools/matmut_logging.py
-rw-rw-rw-  2.0 fat     2047 b- defN 22-Jun-13 06:37 matmuttools/proxy.py
-rw-rw-rw-  2.0 fat      928 b- defN 22-Jun-13 06:37 matmuttools/singleton.py
-rw-rw-rw-  2.0 fat      257 b- defN 22-Jun-13 06:37 matmuttools/hadoop/__init__.py
-rw-rw-rw-  2.0 fat     9891 b- defN 22-Jun-13 06:37 matmuttools/hadoop/hdfs_wrapper.py
-rw-rw-rw-  2.0 fat    10465 b- defN 22-Jun-13 06:37 matmuttools/hadoop/impala_wrapper.py
-rw-rw-rw-  2.0 fat      120 b- defN 22-Sep-29 09:22 matmuttools/ql/__init__.py
-rw-rw-rw-  2.0 fat     2159 b- defN 22-Sep-29 12:19 matmuttools/ql/query_language.py
-rw-rw-rw-  2.0 fat      478 b- defN 22-Sep-29 11:56 matmuttools/ql/tsql.py
-rw-rw-rw-  2.0 fat      454 b- defN 22-Sep-30 09:08 matmuttools-3.2.0.dist-info/METADATA
-rw-rw-rw-  2.0 fat       97 b- defN 22-Sep-30 09:08 matmuttools-3.2.0.dist-info/WHEEL
-rw-rw-rw-  2.0 fat       12 b- defN 22-Sep-30 09:08 matmuttools-3.2.0.dist-info/top_level.txt
?rw-rw-r--  2.0 fat     1155 b- defN 22-Sep-30 09:08 matmuttools-3.2.0.dist-info/RECORD
14 files, 38057 bytes uncompressed, 10720 bytes compressed:  71.8%
```

---

It seems the MANIFEST.in is not even used. Adding `prune matmuttools/ql` to it does nothing. The content of the wheel is the same as above.

Comment: I can't think of a reason why that `MANIFEST.in` configuration wouldn't work. What happens if you just build the wheel locally (e.g. install the `build` package and `python -m build .`) and look at what's inside (wheels are zips, so `zipinfo something.whl`)?

Comment: @AKX done. Question updated with result.

Comment: Okay, can you also add the full `setup.py`? Have you tried updating your version of `setuptools`?

Comment: The file doesn't belong to `matmuttools` package but to `matmuttools.ql` subpackage so try this: `package_data={'matmuttools.ql': ['*.ini']}`

Comment: Wouhoo ! That was it @phd. Thanks. I'll accept your answer when you write one. But I don't get why the syntax in the manifest is not "working".

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]? A Git repo would be the best; not necessary your exact code.

Comment: Here you go: https://github.com/Andromelus/ilikeapples

Comment: Nice! I'm gonna to push a number of Pull Requests with comments — not to merge but to read and discuss.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The file `default_config.ini` doesn't belong to `matmuttools` package but to `matmuttools.ql` subpackage so fix it this way:

```
package_data={'matmuttools.ql': ['*.ini']}
```